# How does one access apps on Android Wear 2?

Tags: android-wear

My Huawei updated to Android Wear 2 and now I can't find my apps. I have swiped in every direction but none appear. I cannot find a comprehensive manual of controls (though Google searches happily return scads of useless tips-and-tricks articles in long-form prose).

Answer (score 0):

A single press of the primary hardware button now opens the apps drawer. Before the update this would turn off the screen.